# Building a Python library from a c++ program?

Tags: python, c++, module, swig

I'm still incredibly new to all of this, so I apologize if I'm not providing the correct info, or presenting my issues properly.

- Python Version: [3.11]
- Operating System: [Windows 11 x64]
- Ebsynth .dll/program: [Built from source](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ebsynth+github&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&lq=0&pq=ebsynth+githu&sc=10-13&sk=&cvid=AD56A2584D5B43DCA1809A9673BE8905&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=)

### Context:

I'm trying to create a new python module/library using the Ebsynth c++ program, which already creates a .dll that exposes functions externally. I'm using a Python binding for the library that was generated using SWIG.

### Problem:

When I call the ebsynthRun function, I'm getting a TypeError with the message: "in method 'ebsynthRun', argument 6 of type 'void *'". This suggests that the function is having trouble with the sourceStyleData parameter, which is supposed to be a pointer to the data of my source style image.

### What I've tried:

I've tried loading the image data using OpenCV, converting it to a numpy array, and then flattening the array to create a 1D array. I'm passing this 1D array as the sourceStyleData parameter.

I've tried converting the numpy array to a ctypes array to match the 'void *' pointer type that the ebsynthRun function expects. This is done by calling .ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8)) on the numpy array.

I've tried using numpy.ascontiguousarray to ensure that the data in the numpy array is stored in a contiguous block of memory.

### Images:

I'm using RGB images and I'm making sure to account for all three color channels in my code.

### Additional Info:

The ebsynthRun function also takes sourceGuideData and targetGuideData parameters, which I'm setting to the same data as sourceStyleData. These parameters are also of type 'void *' and may be causing similar issues. I know that the c++ code is probably correct, as the ebsynthBackendAvailable function works properly when called from python.

### Error Messages:

```
CPU Backend Available: 1
CUDA Backend Available: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ebsynth2\bin\info.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\ebsynth2\bin\info.py", line 45, in main
    ebsynth.ebsynthRun(
  File "c:\ebsynth2\bin\ebsynth.py", line 73, in ebsynthRun
    return _ebsynth.ebsynthRun(ebsynthBackend, numStyleChannels, numGuideChannels, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, sourceStyleData, sourceGuideData, targetWidth, targetHeight, targetGuideData, targetModulationData, styleWeights, guideWeights, uniformityWeight, patchSize, voteMode, numPyramidLevels, numSearchVoteItersPerLevel, extraPass3x3, outputNnfData, outputImageData)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: in method 'ebsynthRun', argument 6 of type 'void *'
```

### The header file used to create the SWIG Wrapper:

```
// This software is in the public domain. Where that dedication is not
// recognized, you are granted a perpetual, irrevocable license to copy
// and modify this file as you see fit.

#ifndef EBSYNTH_H
#define EBSYNTH_H

#ifndef EBSYNTH_API
  #ifdef WIN32
    #define EBSYNTH_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #else
    #define EBSYNTH_API
  #endif
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define EBSYNTH_BACKEND_CPU         0x0001
#define EBSYNTH_BACKEND_CUDA        0x0002
#define EBSYNTH_BACKEND_AUTO        0x0000

#define EBSYNTH_MAX_STYLE_CHANNELS  8
#define EBSYNTH_MAX_GUIDE_CHANNELS  24

#define EBSYNTH_VOTEMODE_PLAIN      0x0001         // weight = 1
#define EBSYNTH_VOTEMODE_WEIGHTED   0x0002         // weight = 1/(1+error)

EBSYNTH_API
int ebsynthBackendAvailable(int ebsynthBackend);   // returns non-zero if the specified backend is available

EBSYNTH_API
void ebsynthRun(int    ebsynthBackend,             // use BACKEND_CUDA for maximum speed, BACKEND_CPU for compatibility, or BACKEND_AUTO to auto-select

                int    numStyleChannels,
                int    numGuideChannels,

                int    sourceWidth,
                int    sourceHeight,
                void*  sourceStyleData,            // (width * height * numStyleChannels) bytes, scan-line order
                void*  sourceGuideData,            // (width * height * numGuideChannels) bytes, scan-line order

                int    targetWidth,
                int    targetHeight,
                void*  targetGuideData,            // (width * height * numGuideChannels) bytes, scan-line order
                void*  targetModulationData,       // (width * height * numGuideChannels) bytes, scan-line order; pass NULL to switch off the modulation

                float* styleWeights,               // (numStyleChannels) floats
                float* guideWeights,               // (numGuideChannels) floats

                                                   // guideError(txy,sxy,ch) = guideWeights[ch] * (targetModulation[txy][ch]/255) * (targetGuide[txy][ch]-sourceGuide[sxy][ch])^2

                float  uniformityWeight,           // reasonable values are between 500-15000, 3500 is a good default

                int    patchSize,                  // odd sizes only, use 5 for 5x5 patch, 7 for 7x7, etc.
                int    voteMode,                   // use VOTEMODE_WEIGHTED for sharper result

                int    numPyramidLevels,

                int*   numSearchVoteItersPerLevel, // how many search/vote iters to perform at each level (array of ints, coarse first, fine last)
                int*   numPatchMatchItersPerLevel, // how many Patch-Match iters to perform at each level (array of ints, coarse first, fine last)

                int*   stopThresholdPerLevel,      // stop improving pixel when its change since last iteration falls under this threshold

                int    extraPass3x3,               // perform additional polishing pass with 3x3 patches at the finest level, use 0 to disable
                
                void*  outputNnfData,              // (width * height * 2) ints, scan-line order; pass NULL to ignore
                void*  outputImageData             // (width * height * numStyleChannels) bytes, scan-line order
                );


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: I would ONLY use swig if you need to support more than one language besides c++ and python.  If you are only doing c++/python then use boost::python, pybind11 or nanobind.